# Program Compiles, but array out of bounds when ran?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

My code compiles fine, but when I run it I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
>     at Sudoku.(Sudoku.java:20)    at Test.main(Test.java:7)

The code is as follows:

Main Test class:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Sudoku puzzle;

        int[][] entries = {{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,3},{0,0,4,0},{0,4,0,0}};
        puzzle = new Sudoku(2,2,entries);

        boolean somethingChanged=true;
        while(somethingChanged) {
            somethingChanged=false;
            System.out.println(puzzle);

            for (int i=0; i<puzzle.size; i++)
                for(int j=0; j<puzzle.size; j++)
                    if(puzzle.oneOption(i, j)!=puzzle.EMPTY) {
                        // exactly one value can be filled in at location i,j
                        // do this now, and record that something has changed
                        // compared to the previous iteration of the while loop
                        puzzle.setValue(i,j,puzzle.oneOption(i,j));
                        somethingChanged=true;
                    }
            }

        // if oneOption is implemented correctly, the puzzle is now solved!
        System.out.println(puzzle);
    }
}
```

and my uncommented Sudoku Class:

```
class Sudoku {

    int cellHeight, cellWidth, size,EMPTY = 0;
    int [][] sudGrid = new int[cellHeight * cellWidth][cellHeight * cellWidth];
    int [][] cellGrid = new int [cellHeight][cellWidth];

    public Sudoku(int a, int b){
        cellHeight = a;
        cellWidth = b;
        size = cellHeight*cellWidth;
    }

    public Sudoku(int a, int b, int array[][]){
        cellHeight = a;
        cellWidth = b;
        size = cellHeight*cellWidth;
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
                int temp = array[i][j];
                sudGrid[i][j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }

    public Sudoku(){
        cellHeight = 3;
        cellWidth = 3;
        size = cellHeight*cellWidth;
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++)
            for(int j = 0; j<size; j++)
                sudGrid[i][j] = 0;
    }

    public void setValue(int r,int c, int v){
        sudGrid[r][c] = v;
    }

    public int getValue(int r, int c){
        return sudGrid[r][c];
    }

    public void clear(int r, int c){
        sudGrid[r][c] = EMPTY;
    }

    public String toString(){
        String message = "";
        for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
           for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
               message = message + sudGrid[i][j];
               if (j == cellWidth){
                   message = message + " ";
               }
            }
            message = message + "\n";
        }
        return message;
    }

    public int oneOption(int r, int c){
         return 1;
    }
}
```

Sorry, I know this is a lot of code to splat on the screen, but I haven't done a lot on arrays, let alone two dimensional.  I know my `oneOption()` method at the moment does nothing, I just needed it to compile, but where the errors are, is

```
int temp = array[i][j];
sudGrid[i][j] = temp;
```

and

```
int[][] entries = {{1,0,0,0},{0,0,0,3},{0,0,4,0},{0,4,0,0}};
puzzle = new Sudoku(2,2,entries);
```

Now I assumed where the entries array is declared is correct as this is code that my lecturer has set up for us, and we are only designing the Sudoku class. and I was trying to make the values of the entries array, go into the sudGrid array, I assumed I did it correctly, but im getting the exception error,

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `subgrid` is defined as a zero length two dimensional array, so you can't fit anything in there.

See here:

```
int cellHeight, cellWidth, size,EMPTY = 0;
int [][] sudGrid = new int[cellHeight * cellWidth][cellHeight * cellWidth];
```

`cellHeight` and `cellWidth` are initialized to zero by default, then you create a `new int[0*0][0*0]` array.

Change your constructor to the following:

```
public Sudoku(int a, int b, int array[][]){
    cellHeight = a; // Changing these two instance variables will *NOT*
    cellWidth = b;  // retrofit your subGrid to a new size.
    size = cellHeight*cellWidth;
    subGrid = new int[size][size];
    for(int i = 0; i<size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j<size; j++){
            int temp = array[i][j];
            sudGrid[i][j] = temp;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, i did that, but now my other methods cannot access the array? How do i make this possible?

Comment: Just keep the original declaration where you had (although you can omit the initialization) it, so it stays an instance variable.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting your `Sudoku.size` to be the entire number of cells in the puzzle, and then trying to read that many rows and columns. You need to iterate just to the number of columns and rows.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention, the parameters a and b that the constructors take are the rows and columns per cell(single Sudoku section) when multiplied together I get the entire length of column or row(doesn't matter) of the entire Sudoku.